# Sound Converter doesn't convert at all. Any clues?

Tags: music, gstreamer

Screen shots - I ran debug in the terminal as suggested from another forum.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try Format Junkie?

Format Junkie is a converter of audio, music and video. You can give it a try.

To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hakermania/format-junkie; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install formatjunkie
```

Comment: hakermania: I installed FJ and its works! Doesn't do m4a but I figure that's cause it's a proprietary format?

Comment: Interesting ! It should do m4a... Maybe it is missing a dependency. Can you open the errors dialog on the bottom right of the program? What errors do you get when you try to convert to m4a files? (you mean from music file to m4a, right?)

Comment: It seems I cannot select m4a when adding an audio file - http://i.imgur.com/taNAj.png

Comment: yes, this is not supported, yet!